# issue when i resize browser window

Tags: css

So i use osclass script with bender theme. When i resize window i can not see all header content. 
Normal size window:
[normal size window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEFEl.png)

And resized windows:
[resized window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO0RW.png)

Here is my css code:

```css
#header{
 background-color:#35C3D9;
 min-width:100%;
 height:auto;
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 margin-bottom:15px;
 padding-bottom:25px
 }
```

Edited*

So i was looking for 5 hours in the source code and i did not found the problem. I am sorry because i tagged this post in php, it was my first one posted.

Here is all css code:

```css
.form-container-box .header{
 background-color:#f7f7f7;
 padding:10px 15px;
 margin-bottom:30px
 }
.form-container-box .header h1{
 margin:0;
 line-height:1.2em
 }
body.search .list-header .actions{
 height:35px
 }
#header{
 background-color:#35C3D9;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 margin-bottom:15px;
 padding-bottom:25px
 }
#header .wrapper{
 position:relative;
 } 
#header .ads_header{
 width:728px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 padding:10px 0px 10px 0px
 }
#header #logo{
 color:#fff;
 font-family:"Osclass";
 border:none;
 font-size:2.7em;
 line-height:1.5em;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-bottom:10px
 }
#header #logo a{
 font-size:1.5em;
 line-height:0.8em;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#fff
 }
#header .publish a{
 background-color:#ce3d27;
 background-color:#ce3d27;
 background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ce3d27),color-stop(100%, #a72915));
 background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ce3d27,#a72915);
 background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ce3d27,#a72915);
 background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ce3d27,#a72915);
 background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ce3d27,#a72915);
 background-image:linear-gradient(top, #ce3d27,#a72915);
 border:solid 1px #8d2a1b;
 border-top-left-radius:3px;
 border-top-right-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
 border-top-left-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
 border-top-right-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
 color:#fff !important;
 line-height:43px;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:0 15px;
 box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 0 #e9988b;
 text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3)
 }
#header #logo span{
 color:#fff;
 font-family:"Osclass";
 font-weight:100;
 text-decoration:none;
 border:none;
 font-size:0.8em;
 line-height:1em;
 display:block
 }
.main-search{
 background-color:#f0f0f0;
 background-image:
 -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f0f0f0),color-stop(100%, #c9c9c9));
 background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0,#c9c9c9);
 background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0,#c9c9c9);
 background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0,#c9c9c9);
 background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0,#c9c9c9);
 background-image:linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0,#c9c9c9);
 width:966px;
 padding:6px;
 height:46px;
 border:solid 1px #989393;
 margin:0 auto;
 box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 1px 0px #fff,0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 position:relative;
 margin-top:15px;
 border-top-left-radius:4px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
 border-top-right-radius:4px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:4px
 }
.main-search .has-placeholder{
 float:none
 }
.main-search input{
 background-color:#f6f6f6;
 border:solid 1px #bfbfbf;
 border-top-left-radius:3px;
 border-top-right-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
 border-top-left-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
 border-top-right-radius:3px
 ;border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
 box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 0 #E0E0E0;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
 color:#646464;
 line-height:43px;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:0 15px;
 box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 0 #d6cece;
 height:43px;
 width:100%
 }
.main-search .selector{
 padding-left:42px;
 padding-right:12px
 }
.main-search .reset-padding{
 padding-left:0px
 }
.main-search .ui-button{
 background-color:#35C3D9;
 background-color:#35C3D9;
 background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #35C3D9),color-stop(100%, #18a7be));
 background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #35C3D9,#18a7be);
 background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #35C3D9,#18a7be);
 background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #35C3D9,#18a7be);
 background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #35C3D9,#18a7be);
 background-image:linear-gradient(top, #35C3D9,#18a7be);
 border:solid 1px #1f91a3;
 border-top-left-radius:3px;
 border-top-right-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
 border-top-left-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
 border-top-right-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
 color:#fff !important;
 line-height:43px;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:0 15px;
 box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 0 #a0e3ed;
 text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 height:43px
 }
.main-search .cell{
 display:table-cell;
 width:100%;
 vertical-align:top
 }
#header .nav{
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 top:10px;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 list-style:none
 }
#header .nav li{
 float:left;
 position:relative
 }
#header .nav li.search,#header .nav li.cat{
 display:none
 }
#header .nav li a,#header .nav li span{
 color:white;font-size:0.875em
 }
#header .nav li{
 color:white
 }
#header .nav li a{
 margin-left:10px
 }
#header .nav li.publish{
 clear:both;
 float:right;
 margin-top:10px
 }
.main-search .select-box .select-box-label{
 line-height:43px
 }
.main-search .select-box select{
 width:auto;
 height:42px
 }
.main-search .select-box-icon{
 top:0px
 }
.wrapper-flash{
 margin-bottom:35px
 }
.list-header{
 margin-bottom:15px;
 z-index:3;
 position:relative
 }
.item-header{
 margin-top:-10px;
 background:#f7f7f7;
 padding:10px;
 border-top-left-radius:4px;
 border-top-right-radius:4px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
 border-top-left-radius:4px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
 border-top-right-radius:4px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
 font-size:0.875em;
 margin-bottom:15px;
 font-size:0.75em
 }
.item-header #type_dates{
 float:right
 }
.item-header #type_dates em{
 font-style:normal
 }
#header{
 padding-bottom:0px
 }
#header{
 height:auto;
 margin-bottom:20px
 }
#header #logo{
 font-size:1.7em;
 letter-spacing:-0.07em;
 padding-top:10px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
 margin-left:10px
 }
#header #logo span{
 display:none
 }
#header .wrapper{
 padding-left:0;
 padding-right:0;
 width:100%;
 position:relative
 }
.main-search{
 top:100%;
 margin-left:0;
 left:0;
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 padding-left:0;
 padding-right:0;
 border-width:0 0 1px 0;
 border-bottom-left-radius:0;
 border-bottom-right-radius:0;
 border-top-left-radius:0;
 border-top-right-radius:0;
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:0
 }
.main-search .cell{
 display:table-cell;
 width:100%;
 padding-left:11px;
 vertical-align:top
 }
.main-search .cell:last-child{
 padding-left:42px;
 padding-right:11px
 }
.main-search input{
 width:100%
 }
.main-search .selector{
 display:none
 }
.main-search .reset-padding{
 padding-left:0px
 }
#header .nav{
 top:0;
 height:100%;
 vertical-align:middle
 }
#header .nav li{
 height:100%
 }
#header .nav li a{
 height:100%;
 padding:0 15px;
 background-color:#23a4b8;
 color:#000;
 display:table;
 border-left:solid 1px #1b7e8d;
 font-size:30px;
 margin-left:0
 }
#header .nav li.active a,#header .nav li a:hover{
 background-color:#1b7e8d;
 color:#fff
 }
#header .nav li .icons:after{
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle
 }
#header .nav li{
 display:none
 }
#header .nav li.search,#header .nav li.cat{
 display:block
 }
body.display-search #header,body.home #header{
 margin-bottom:80px
 }
body.search .list-header{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
 left:0;
 height:80px
 }
body.search .list-header .actions{
 padding:10px 0;
 clear:both
 }
#header .ads_header,.ads_300,.ads_728,.ads_468{
 display:none
 }
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section{
 display:block
 }
.clear{
 clear:both
 }
.r-list li>li:nth-child(4n),.r-list li .clear{
 clear:both
 }
.wrapper-flash{
 font-weight:bold
 }
.wrapper{
 width:980px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto
 }
.wrapper,#footer{
 padding-left:10px;
 padding-right:10px;
 width:auto
 }
.resp-wrapper{
 padding:0 10px
 }
#description{
 clear:both;
 padding-top:5px
 }
input[type="search"]{
 -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
 -ms-box-sizing:content-box;
 -o-box-sizing:content-box;
 box-sizing:content-box;
 -webkit-appearance:textfield
 }
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button{
 -webkit-appearance:none
 }
.searchPaginationSelected,.paginate a:hover{
 font-weight:bold;
 background-color:#35C3D9;
 color:white
 }
.ico-search:after{
 content:"s"
 }
body.search #sidebar,body.user #sidebar{
 float:left;
 width:210px
 }
body.search #main,body.user #main{
 float:right;
 width:728px
 }
.counter-search{
 float:left;
 line-height:32px
 }
#related-searches{
 padding-top:25px
 }
#related-searches h5{
 margin-bottom:10px;
 font-size:1em
 }
body.search .listing-grid .last{
 margin-right:0px
 }
body.search .listing-grid .listing-card{
 width:161px
 }
.item #comments .pagination a.searchPaginationSelected{
 background-color:#f7f7f7
 }
.item #comments .pagination a.searchPaginationNext,.item #comments a.searchPaginationPrev,.item #comments .pagination a.searchPaginationFirst,.item #comments a.searchPaginationLast{
 border:0px;
 text-decoration:none
 }
.item #comments .pagination a.searchPaginationNext:hover,.item #comments a.searchPaginationPrev:hover,.item #comments .pagination a.searchPaginationFirst:hover,.item #comments a.searchPaginationLast:hover{
 background-color:#ffffff
 }
div#main,body.home #main,body.search #main,body.user #main,body.item #main,body.user-public-profile #main{
 width:auto;
 float:none;
 clear:both
 }
body.display-search .main-search,body.home .main-search{
 display:table
 }
.listing-grid .listing-card,body.search .listing-grid .listing-card{
 width:32%;
 padding:0%;
 border:0;
 margin:1%
 }
.listing-grid .listing-card:nth-child(3n),body.search .listing-card:nth-child(3n){
 margin-right:0%
 }
.listing-grid .listing-card:nth-child(3n+1),body.search .listing-grid .listing-card:nth-child(3n+1){
 margin-left:0%;
 clear:both
 }
body.search #sidebar,body.user #sidebar{
 width:auto;
 float:none;
 margin-bottom:40px
 }
body.search #content{
 position:relative;
 padding-top:100px
 }
body.search #sidebar,body.user #sidebar{
 display:none;
 background-color:#f7f7f7;
 border:solid 1px #eaeaea;
 padding:10px 15px 5px;
 width:auto;float:none;
 border-top-left-radius:4px;
 border-top-right-radius:4px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
 border-top-left-radius:4px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
 border-top-right-radius:4px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:4px
 }
body.search #content h1{
 display:block;
 margin:0;
 font-size:1.5em
 }
ul.r-list>li:nth-child(2n),body.search ul.r-list>li:nth-child(2n){
 padding-left:0px
 }
.listing-grid .listing-card,body.search .listing-grid .listing-card{
 width:49%;
 clear:none
 }
.listing-grid .listing-card:nth-child(2n),body.search .listing-grid .listing-card:nth-child(2n){
 margin-right:0%;
 margin-left:1%;
 clear:none
 }
.listing-grid .listing-card:nth-child(2n+1),body.search .listing-grid .listing-card:nth-child(2n+1){
 margin-left:0%;
 margin-right:1%;
 clear:both !important
 }
#footer .resp-toogle .publish{
 padding:0;
 margin:15px 0;
 display:block
 }
#footer .resp-toogle .publish a{
 background-color:#d94b35;
 background-color:#d94b35;
 background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #d94b35),color-stop(100%, #be2e18));
 background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d94b35,#be2e18);
 background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #d94b35,#be2e18);
 background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #d94b35,#be2e18);
 background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #d94b35,#be2e18);
 background-image:linear-gradient(top, #d94b35,#be2e18);
 border:solid 1px #a3301f;
 border-top-left-radius:3px;
 border-top-right-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
 border-top-left-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
 border-top-right-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
 color:#fff !important;
 line-height:43px;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:0 15px;
 box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 0 #edaba0;
 text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 width:100%;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
 -o-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 margin:0;
 font-size:1.2em;
 padding:0
 }
div.breadcrumb{
 line-height:1.05em;
 font-size:0.75em;
 height:auto;
 margin:0;
 width:auto;
 padding:10px 0;
 border-bottom:1px solid #eaeaea
 }
ul.breadcrumb{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
 }
ul.breadcrumb li{
 float:left;
 padding:0 2px;
 font-weight:normal
 }
.ui-button-main{
 background-color:#35C3D9;
 background-color:#35C3D9;
 background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #35C3D9),color-stop(100%, #18a7be));
 background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #35C3D9,#18a7be);
 background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #35C3D9,#18a7be);
 background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #35C3D9,#18a7be);
 background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #35C3D9,#18a7be);
 background-image:linear-gradient(top, #35C3D9,#18a7be);
 border:solid 1px #1f91a3;
 border-top-left-radius:3px;
 border-top-right-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
 border-top-left-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
 border-top-right-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
 color:#fff !important;
 line-height:43px;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:0 15px;
 box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 0 #a0e3ed;
 text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3)
 }
body.home #main{
 width:640px;
 float:left;
 margin-top:-20px 40px 0 0
 }
#main h5{
 margin-bottom:10px
 }
body.item #main,body.user-public-profile #main{
 width:640px;
 float:left
 }
.cell_3{
 width:33%;
 float:left
 }
.cell_3 ul{
 margin:0;
 margin-left:20px
 }
div.cell_3:nth-child(2n){
 margin:0 1%;
 width:31%
 }
body div.cell_3,body div.cell_3:nth-child(2n){
 margin:0;
 width:100%
 }
```

and php code:

```js
<?php

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="<?php echo str_replace('_', '-', osc_current_user_locale()); ?>">
    <head>
        <?php osc_current_web_theme_path('common/head.php') ; ?>
    </head>
<body <?php sagap_body_class(); ?>>
<div id="header">
    <!-- header ad 728x60-->
    <div class="ads_header">
    <?php echo osc_get_preference('header-728x90', 'sagap'); ?>
    <!-- /header ad 728x60-->
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="logo">
            <?php echo logo_header(); ?>
            <span id="description"><?php echo osc_page_description(); ?></span>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav">
            <?php if( osc_is_static_page() || osc_is_contact_page() ){ ?>
                <li class="search"><a class="ico-search icons" data-bclass-toggle="display-search"></a></li>
                <li class="cat"><a class="ico-menu icons" data-bclass-toggle="display-cat"></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if( osc_users_enabled() ) { ?>
            <?php if( osc_is_web_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
                <li class="first logged">
                    <span><?php echo sprintf(__('Hi %s', 'sagap'), osc_logged_user_name() . '!'); ?>  &middot;</span>
                    <strong><a href="<?php echo osc_user_dashboard_url(); ?>"><?php _e('My account', 'sagap'); ?></a></strong> &middot;
                    <a href="<?php echo osc_user_logout_url(); ?>"><?php _e('Logout', 'sagap'); ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <li><a id="login_open" href="<?php echo osc_user_login_url(); ?>"><?php _e('Login', 'sagap') ; ?></a></li>
                <?php if(osc_user_registration_enabled()) { ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo osc_register_account_url() ; ?>"><?php _e('Register for a free account', 'sagap'); ?></a></li>
                <?php }; ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if( osc_users_enabled() || ( !osc_users_enabled() && !osc_reg_user_post() )) { ?>
            <li class="publish"><a href="<?php echo osc_item_post_url_in_category() ; ?>"><?php _e("Publish your ad for free", 'sagap');?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <?php if( osc_is_home_page() || osc_is_static_page() || osc_is_contact_page() ) { ?>
    <form action="<?php echo osc_base_url(true); ?>" method="get" class="search nocsrf" <?php /* onsubmit="javascript:return doSearch();"*/ ?>>
        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="search"/>
        <div class="main-search">
            <div class="cell">
                <input type="text" name="sPattern" id="query" class="input-text" value="" placeholder="<?php echo osc_esc_html(__(osc_get_preference('keyword_placeholder', 'sagap'), 'sagap')); ?>" />
            </div>
            <?php  if ( osc_count_categories() ) { ?>
                <div class="cell selector">
                    <?php osc_categories_select('sCategory', null, __('Select a category', 'sagap')) ; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="cell reset-padding">
            <?php  } else { ?>
                <div class="cell">
            <?php  } ?>
                <button class="ui-button ui-button-big js-submit"><?php _e("Search", 'sagap');?></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="message-seach"></div>
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php osc_show_widgets('header'); ?>
<div class="wrapper wrapper-flash">
    <?php
        $breadcrumb = osc_breadcrumb('&raquo;', false, get_breadcrumb_lang());
        if( $breadcrumb !== '') { ?>
        <div class="breadcrumb">
            <?php echo $breadcrumb; ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    <?php osc_show_flash_message(); ?>
</div>
<?php osc_run_hook('before-content'); ?>
<div class="wrapper" id="content">
    <?php osc_run_hook('before-main'); ?>
    <div id="main">
        <?php osc_run_hook('inside-main'); ?>
```

Comment: It is a problem with the width of a containing element. Take a look at any divs or other elements that are higher up the tree from this #header element.

Comment: why is this tagged php?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be Minimal, Complete, Verifiable. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve